# SceneKit Node Lighting

Tags: swift, 3d, textures, scenekit, lighting

I have a scenekit node that I want to add a glow effect to.

```
let newScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/cubeOne.scn")!
let newNode = (newScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cubeOneNode", recursively: false))!

newNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.selfIllumination = UIColor.red
newNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.ambientOcclusion = UIColor.red

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newNode)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using a so called CIFilter and attach it to you node - but I personally don't recommend this, because it is incredibly performance intense and uses like three times more memory.

I recommend configuring this on your camera. It will also cost you more GPU performance and some memory, but not as much as a CIFilter does. Give it a try:

```
camera.wantsHDR                     = true
camera.bloomThreshold               = 0.8
camera.bloomIntensity               = 2
camera.bloomBlurRadius              = 16.0
camera.wantsExposureAdaptation      = false
```

and then use the `emission.intensity` property of the node material. Set it between `2.0` to `5.0`, depending on how much you want the effect to be visible. I usually use the `.physicallyBased` lighting option for my on scene stuff. (I never tried to use it with `selfIllumination`.)

*PS: Using the red color does not add a very intense effect. Really intense is cyan or green. Using the red color you might screw up the `emission.intensity` value to `10.0` or higher.*

Comment: thanks! I'm already using a lot of resources, so it sounds like I may want to avoid doing this. I appreciate the detailed response. WoW.