How to set SCNTechnique for SK3DNode
I am following some sample code (https://github.com/laanlabs/SCNTechniqueGlow) to add border to a 3d model using SCNTechnique. The code sets the technique to SCNView:
  scnView.technique = technique

However, I am using SK3DNode, so I don't have a SCNView to work with. So how can i support it?
Edit:
I thought I could set the camera.technique (rather than scnView.technique). However, I got the following failure when doing so:

-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setRenderPipelineState:]:1616: failed assertion `Set Render Pipeline State Validation
For depth attachment, the render pipeline's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatInvalid) does not match the framebuffer's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float_Stencil8).

Edit:
Please download sample project here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXycL1ITnYwMQSC_Er9FeWE3LKvnhiAf/view?usp=sharing
When you run it, it will show 2 views before it crashes (see the screenshot below).
The top view is a SCNView with a SCNScene, and the technique works (as you can see the yellow border).
The bottom view is a SKView with a SK3DNode that contains the same SCNScene, and the technique doesn't work (no yellow border), and it causes the crash.


One of the simplest tricks is to set Bloom on a HDR Camera. Here Is an old article with an answer I wrote, that describes this scenario. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195349/scenekit-node-lighting) I never tested it with SpriteKit integration. There are other methods as well, like CIFilter, SCNTechnique, or Shader Modifyers. Some of them are really Performance intense, some just a little bit. Bloom on a HDR Camera is quite lightweight.

@ZAY I thought I could set camera.technique. However, that doesn't work. I have updated the question.

can you share, what you have done so far?

@ZAY i have included a sample project. Thank you!

I currently have no solution for you regarding this issue. In the SpriteKit Scene I can see the technique, but it's very offset from the Node, on which you want to add glow. What about adding a small real SCNView in a UIView, and add this to your project, instead of using the SpriteKit integrated SceneKit Stuff, which might have limitations. I am not at all familiar with SpriteKit integrated 3D stuff, sorry at this point.
